# How to initialise an array of Strings?

Tags: java

How to create and initialize a string array of size, say, 100?

```
String[] str=new String(100);
```

This doesn't seem to work.

Update: I was just having difficulty with the constructor. Silly thing, I know. But thanks for the quick help, guys.

Comment: `String[] str = new String[100]`.  Be sure to use Google.

Comment: Initialize with what?

Comment: @Andrew I was just having difficulty with the constructor part. Silly thing, I know.

Answer (score 5):

This is a two-step process.

The first step is allocate the array:

```
String[] str = new String[100];
```

This creates an array of 100 `String` references all set to `null`.

The second step is to set those references to point to some strings. This can, for example, be done using a `for` loop.

Comment: There is also a very convenient `Arrays.fill()` method to fill arrays

Answer (score 5):

```
String[] str = new String[100];
```

or

```
String[] str = new String[100];
str[0] = "a";
str[1] = "b";
str[2] = "c";
.....
.....
str[98] = "dd";
str[99] = "ee";
```

Alternatively,

```
String[] str= { "a", "b", "c" };
```

Answer (score 2):

Array should be initialized:

```
String[] arrayOfStrings = new String[100];   
arrayOfStrings[0] = "str1";
arrayOfStrings[1] = "str2";
```

Array with values in java 7

```
String[] arrayOfStrings = {"str1", "str2"};
```

Array with values in java 6 and lower

```
String[] arrayOfStrings = new String[]{"str1", "str2"};
```

read more about array here : [Oracle Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use square brackets for array:

```
String[] str=new String[100];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] str = new String[100];
```

Answer (score 1):

syntax is as follows

```
String[] str=new String[100];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
String[] str=new String[100];     // 100 is size of array
str[0]="item1";                 // initialization
str[1]="item2"
.
.
str[99]="item100";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String[] str = new String[100];
```